# Add a UIView near to row's button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have tableview with sections and rows. When user clicks on button inside a row/section it will display `UIView` near to that particular button.

```
- (IBAction) openRoundedPopover:(id)sender {

btn = (UIButton*)  sender;

//Identify if user clicked header section or cell row
if (btn.titleLabel.tag == 8)
    isHeaderViewButtonClicked = YES; // headerview mean when user clicks on section
else
    isHeaderViewButtonClicked = NO;

MainTableViewCell *clickedResourceCell = (MainTableViewCell*)btn.superview.superview;
CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];

self.roundedButtonMenu.frame = CGRectMake(43, isHeaderViewButtonClicked ? hitPoint.y+50:clickedResourceCell.frame.origin.y+53, self.roundedButtonMenu.frame.size.width, self.roundedButtonMenu.frame.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:self.roundedButtonMenu];

}
```

These all working fine. But when the user keep adding rows/sections and clicks on buttons of bottom rows/sections (i.e. scrolls tableview to bottom to view newly added rows/sections) it won't show `UIView` near to that button. It popups somewhere else or not showing up at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
MainTableViewCell *clickedResourceCell = (MainTableViewCell*)btn.superview.superview;
```

don't assume a view hierachy you have no control over. **(this will 110% break in the near ios future)**

So I assume you dont get the cell's frame!

```
MainTableViewCell *clickedResourceCell = (MainTableViewCell*)btn; 
while(clickedResourceCell.superview && ![clickedResourceCell isKindOfClass:[MainTableViewCell class]]) {
    clickedResourceCell = (MainTableViewCell*)clickedResourceCell.superview;
}
```

---

but your problem is that you add the button to elf.view which is not in the scrollview.. the calculation cant really work when scrolling, can it?

add it to the cell:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,40); //dummy
 [cell.contentView addSubview:btw];
//take care of cell reusing!
```

Comment: Hi Daij, Thank you for the answer! I've updated my code like you said, but still it's not working! UIView not appearing when user scrolls the tableview to bottom. But it's really helpful for correcting my mistake in retrieving cell value in wrong way.Thanks alot!

Comment: edited a bit ... if you have cells that can be scrolled, adding the button to the view doesn't work

Comment: but when you add it to the cell (as is proper!) you have to take care to add/remove it in cellForRow: [if you reuse  cells]

Comment: YES, your code snippet is working only when I clicks on section button not on the row button. Why is that?